# Suitable data structure for computing progressive tax

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Company A has its own system that it uses to levy taxes on the sellers. The taxes are computed in a progressive manner. For eg. if the seller sells goods worth $25 then for the first 10 dollars tax=8% and on remaining 15 dollars tax = 7%. So total tax= 8% of 25 + 7% of 15.

The table that they use to compute the tax is as follows

```
$0 - $10 8%
$11 - $50 7%
$51 - $500 6%
$501 - $10000 5%
$10001 -$1000000 4% and so on.
```

Which data structure would you use to store this table and how would you use that data structure to code a function
`float computeTaxableAmount(float amount) {}`

Answer (score 3):

I'd use an array of structs.  Consider:

```
fields: from  to    percentage cumulative

values: 0     10    0.08       0
        10    50    0.07       0.80 (= (to-from)*percentage from row above)
        50    500   0.06       0.80 + (50-10)*0.07 = 4.00
        500   10000 0.05       4.00 + (500-50)*0.06 = 31.00
        ...
```

Notice the cumulative field: a running total of the combined tax implied by simply having reached the tax bracket in question.  Then, say you want the tax for some sales of X dollars, you find the row encompassing X (i.e. `from <= X < to`) and the total tax will be:

```
(X - from) * percentage + cumulative
```

The precalculation of the combined tax of earlier tax brackets saves pointless repetition of the math during program execution.

You could binary search to find the single tax bracket X falls into, but - given there's so few elements - the overhead of calculating/moving the probing positions may cost more than the "misses" from searching linearly.  (If desperate or bored, there are some nano-optimisations you could explore, like starting from the middle row to minimise worse-case misses, or starting from the row you last matched if input values tend to be similar etc..)

Comment: Thanks Tony. During the interview, it did not click me that I could store the cumulative percentages too. I was calculating it everytime and that was making it complicated.

Comment: @kag: You're welcome.  Don't feel too bad about it: the performance difference is probably so slight in this case, I'd be as likely to let it recalculate too, even with prior knowledge of this kind of optimisation.